# Ruby uninitialized constant BaseHelper (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi I am having a problem which is driving me mad, When my code complies I receive the error

```
uninitialized constant BaseHelper (NameError)
```

My code had been working completely fine, up until the point where I added another subclass (AccessoriesMerchandise)
my classes look like this

BaseHelper class:

```
class BaseHelper

def find(locator)
  @browser.find_element locator
end

def type(locator, input)
  find(locator).send_keys input
end

end
```

Child class:

```
class FindADealerPage < BaseHelper


#PageObjects
FIND_A_DEALER_SEARCH_FIELD =    {id: "abcd"}
MAP_TAB   =                     {css: 'abcd abcd abcd'}
SERVICE_CHECK_BOX =             {class: "abcd"}
SUBMIT_SEARCH =                 {class: "abcd"}
DEALER_RESULTS_FIRST_DEALER =   {css: "abcd"}

def initialize(browser, wait)
  @browser = browser
  @wait = wait
end

def go_to_find_a_dealer_page
  @browser.get $base_url
end
end
```

They are both sitting in the same folder! I added this class where my problems started.

```
class AccessoriesMerchandise < BaseHelper

    #PageObjects
    ACCESSORIES_ACCORDION        = {css: 'div.mesSpecAccordion.accessoriesAccordion'}
    PANEL_CLOSED                 = {css: 'h2.trigger'}
    PANEL_OPENED_ACTIVE          = {css: 'h2.trigger.active'}

    def initialize(browser, wait)
      @browser = browser
      @wait = wait
    end

    def go_to_page
      @browser.get $base_url
    end

    end
```

This class is also sitting in the same folder.
The framework I am using is, Ruby Selenium WebDriver, Cucumber and Rspec Expectations

Comment: you need to `require` it on child class file like `require base_helper.rb`

Comment: but then why was it working before without any requires? also do you need a require if they are both sitting in the same folder?

Comment: yes as it In order to create reusable components--ones that can be easily used in other programs--a programming language must have some way of smoothly importing that code at run-time. In Ruby, the require method is used to load another file and execute all its statements. This serves to import all class and method definitions in the file. In addition to simply executing all of the statements in the file, the require method also keeps track of which files have been previously required and, thus, will not require a file twice.

Comment: ok require alone didn't work but require File.expand_path('../base_helper.rb', __FILE__) did Thanks

Comment: It probably worked before, because your framework loads all the files in the folder, probably in alphabetical order.  So base_helper.rb was already loaded by the time find_a_dealer.rb was loaded, so the constant `BaseHelper` was available.  But when you added accessories.rb, it got loaded before base_helper.rb, and the constant `BaseHelper` was not available.  As the other posters have explained, a `require` will bring in the file you need when you need it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `require` it

It should be something like [As you told both are in same folder]

```
require 'base_helper.rb'

class FindADealerPage < BaseHelper
 #PageObjects
  FIND_A_DEALER_SEARCH_FIELD =    {id: "abcd"}
  MAP_TAB   =                     {css: 'abcd abcd abcd'}
  SERVICE_CHECK_BOX =             {class: "abcd"}
  SUBMIT_SEARCH =                 {class: "abcd"}
  DEALER_RESULTS_FIRST_DEALER =   {css: "abcd"}

  def initialize(browser, wait)
   @browser = browser
   @wait = wait
  end
 ...
end
```